# How to build Instagram REDIRECT URI dynamically?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, instagram

i'm trying to send a `get` request to Instagram API, after authentication, like this

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/
```

to get user data. It works when I set a static URL like `www.WebSite.com` but when 
I'm trying to overwrite the `REDIRECT URI` that I set in my Instagram App but it gives me this error:

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}
```

I'm trying to build the URL dynamically for `REDIRECT URI` like this:

```
$client->redirect_uri = home_url() . '/user-profile/'.wp_get_current_user()->ID .'/';
```

so please any help on how we can overwrite the `REDIRECT URI`. many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It may be a dumb question, but did you ever tried to visually match the redirect URI you've registered while creating the Instagram API access to the one you're building and setting to `$client->redirect_uri` for any issues like trailing spaces, rogue characters, etc?

Comment: i have a user profile and every user have id and i'm passing the id in the URL for every user and i need the Instagram link in this page so i can't set the  REDIRECT URI as static. and yes i tried to  match the redirect URI and it work as i mention that on my question

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should match the redirect `URI` you set in your Instagram app, pass the user id as a query parameter (e.g. `?id=1`), and then get it from the `$_GET` array.
You can find the rules of valid `URI` matching in [Instagram Developer Documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/?hl=en)

[image]